# android easy parker application where user enters area and gets the list of building names in the spinner

Tags: java, php, android, json, import

I'm creating a android application where the user enters the area , that area has to be sent to the WEB SERVER and receive back data(building names) of that area from the web server.

I'm getting error for array list  could you please provide solution. I don't no how to send data through json object and receive data from json object

MainActivity.java

*package com.androidbegin.Json;*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.json.R;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<String> buildinglist;
    ArrayList<Buildings> buildings;
 EditText area;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.122.1/abc.php?area="+area);

                    }
            });
    new DownloadJSON().execute();
    // Download JSON file AsyncTask
    }private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Locate the WorldPopulation Class 
            buildings = new ArrayList<Buildings>();
            // Create an array to populate the spinner 
            buildinglist = new ArrayList<String>();
            // JSON file URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.122.1/json_response.txt");

            try {
                // Locate the NodeList name
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("Buildings");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Buildings worldpop = new Buildings();

                    // Populate spinner with country names
                    buildinglist.add(jsonobject.optString("country"));

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
            Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

            // Spinner adapter
            mySpinner
                    .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                            buildinglist));

            // Spinner on item click listener
            mySpinner
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml
                            TextView txtarea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.building);

                            // Set the text followed by the position 
                            txtarea.setText("area : "
                                    + buildings.get(position).getArea());

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
            }
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace / your logcat record and specify where the error happens.

Comment: no content in the logcat as i cannot run the code since there is an error... its giving an error for line "ArrayList<Buildings>building"  it is an array name in json data .